# Initial submit filter of DateRangePicker widget in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, widget, yii-widgets

I have a problem with DateRangePicker.
If attribute firstly  It is empty , I dont select current day.
[image]
But If was select another day and it work, then I select today It work.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I select today in first time. Is it possible ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have index page and used gridView . 
there is one column which is created_at.  First I enter the page and Filtr select current day and down filter but it is'nt work
But first I was filter another day and then I select current day it work .

I need firstly filter current day